# Android imageView id not showing

Tags: android, imageview, r.java-file, findviewbyid

I have an imageView in my main.xml file, that isn't setup with a source initially. I want to be able to dynamically change the image resource within the code. so lets so i have my imageView setup like this:

```
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/countryImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/CountryImageContent"/>
```

So i try to access within my code like this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.countryImage);
```

The problem is here. Eclipse is giving me an error saying that "countryImage cannot be resolved or is not a field". A quick peek into my R.java file is showing me that the imageView isn't actually in there. Why is this happening? Thanks.

Comment: Few things, 1) Check your xml or other xml files does not have any errors 2) make sure you have R.java added 3) Do a project clean. Tell me the result after this.

Comment: I just did a clean and my R.java file disappeared!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into your drawable and layout if there is any error

if not try cleaning your project

Go to Project > clean > select your project

if not then  look into your imports for

your.packagename.R remove it

Comment: i made the clean, but now my R.java file disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

**Project -> Clean.**

That is the only solution to this.

Also make sure that among your import statements, you **do not have** this : `import android.R`

Check this [link](http://www.mybringback.com/travis-android-help/1/hello-world/) for a detailed procedure.

Note : I am assuming that there are no errors in your layout and drawable files, as errors in them may also lead to this problem.

Comment: i made the clean, but now my R.java file disappeared!

Comment: Please confirm if there is any error in any of your XML files.

Comment: Also, Make sure you are building the project too after cleaning. Try editing any single line, save it and build it again.

Comment: Not working... its showing in the gen folder a BuildConfig.java but building (Clicking project->Build Project) isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

make sure all resource files have only lowercase letters , numbers and the underscore character ("_") .

only if there are no errors in creating the R file (in the "gen" folder) , you can use the id of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the problem to giving the name of `@string`

Please Remove all UpperCase Character from  `@string/CountryImageContent` and replace it with small character.

R.java file doesn't support any Uppercase character. It gives the same error when you declare the file name of any resources Like :- `Image, XML, @string, etc..`.

Just rename `CountryImageContent` with `country_image_content`. it will work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to try in this case is: **File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart...**